# Map data points onto an image in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

[image]

I'd like to be able to plot points onto this image automatically based on a data set in google sheets. Is this possible? If so, how do you do it?

Edit: For example, if I have the data

#1 - 7,8

#2 - 8,7

I'd like to plot those on the map like so:

[image]

First, I think I could have a stored table of the center pixel coordinates of each hex, then vlookup the coordinates (e.g. 8,7) on that table to pull the pixel coordinates. Then I have pixel coordinates to plot on the image, I am just unsure of how to plot them.

Comment: Clarify question and provide a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Explain the current process and what you want the expected result is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a scatterplot on top of it using vlookup to convert the hex coordinates above to x and y pixel coordinates on the image.